# -bash: ‘export: command not found -bash: 400:: command not found both appear on mac terminal

Tags: bash, git, macos, terminal, autocomplete

Both appear when I open up the terminal.

I tried to get git autocompletion by following these instructions:

1. go to terminal
   put the `git-completion.bash` script in your home directory:

   ```sh
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git... -o ~/.git-completion.bash
   ```
2. Add the following line to your: `.bash_profile`; this tells bash to run the git autocomplete script if it exists

   ```sh
   vi ~/.bash_profile
   if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
       . ~/.git-completion.bash
   fi
   ```

But it didn't work, and now I get these two lines when I open the terminal and they won't go away:

```
-bash: ‘export: command not found
-bash: 400:: command not found
```

Comment: Have a look at the output of `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git...`. The URL is truncated, and `~/.git-completion.bash` now contains `400: invalid request`. Which causes the error you see when you try to source it as a Bash file. Remove these lines from `.bash_profile` again, and delete `~/.git-completion.bash`. Then install git completion with homebrew, like described [here](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion).